# The file is never sent in JavaMail

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an attachment by using JavaMail API, and it doesn't sem to work. Can you please tell me the mistake which I am making, the file ABC.pdf is in the same file of the project. I do get the correct path in "s" in the first sysout. The program never reaches the second sysout. I hace replace Id's with "trial" in email id.
Please help

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setSubject("Trial Messages");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("trial@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("trial@yahoo.co.in"));

        MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
        body.setText(content);;
        Multipart part = new MimeMultipart();

        part.addBodyPart(body);

        File f = new File("ABC.pdf");
        String s = f.getAbsolutePath();

        System.out.printf(s);

        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(s);
        body.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        body.setFileName("ABC Bill");
        part.addBodyPart(body);

        System.out.printf(s);
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.printf(s);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
body.setFileName("ABC Bill");
```

with

```
body.setFileName(source.getName());
```

You can try here to passe source.getName() to sysout to see if everything is correct (the right file name)
add also

// add the Multipart to the message

```
message.setContent(part);
```

remove `part.addBodyPart(body);` because you added it twice

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setSubject("Trial Messages");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("trial@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("trial@yahoo.co.in"));

        MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
        body.setText(content);;
        Multipart part = new MimeMultipart();


        File f = new File("ABC.pdf");
        String s = f.getAbsolutePath();

        System.out.printf(s);

        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(s);
        body.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        body.setFileName("ABC Bill");
        part.addBodyPart(body);

        message.setContent(part);
        System.out.printf(s);
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.printf(s);
```

Comment: Okay I added the message.setContent(part); and that seems to solve the problem but now the receipent receives two attachments of the same file.

Comment: remove part.addBodyPart(body); because you added it twice

Comment: @chettyharish  Did it work now? then accept the answer and vote

Comment: It sounds like you've figured it all out, but the original code had two problems - 1) you didn't set the multipart as the content of the message, 2) you reused the MimeBodyPart object for the attachment instead of creating a new MimeBodyPart object.